# Selection of Sidebar item does not display the component

Tags: angular

I want to display a component when the user clicks on the sideNav. For now I was able to display the SideBarNavigation using [ng-simple-sidebar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-simple-sidebar).

When I click on a sidebar Item , the component doesn't get displayed on the side but opens in as a new page. Can someone please help me here.

The code snippet is as follows:

```
constructor(private ngSimpleSidebarService: NgSimpleSidebarService) {
    this.defaultSidebarItems = [
        {
            name: 'Welcome',
            icon: 'fas fa-camera fa-xs',
            routerLink: ['../../welcome'],
            position: 'top',
        },
        {
            name: 'About',
            icon: 'fas fa-camera fa-xs',
            routerLink: ['../../user/signin'],
            position: 'top',
        },
        
    ];
    this.ngSimpleSidebarService.addItems(this.defaultSidebarItems);
    this.ngSimpleSidebarService.configure(this.defaultSidebarConfig);
  }
```

[image]

When I click on an ITEM from (section 1 - shown in the image) the component page should display in section 2 - also shown in the image.

ROUTING MODULE

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path:"" , component:HomeComponent , pathMatch:"full"},
  {path:"user/signin" , component:loginComponent},
  {path:"user/welcome" , component:WelcomeComponent},
  {path:"user/profile" , component:ProfileComponent},


];
```

Comment: Can you explain this: `the component doesn't get displayed on the side but opens in as a new page.`? SPA doesn't load new pages unless we open it. Can you add any visuals and code relevant to it?

Comment: I have posted the code block and also a screenshot to help understand better.

Comment: @Illep can you check your router path is correct in routing module? Because I tried sample in my local It's works fine.

Comment: @ArunkumarRamasamy So do you mean it works for you when you click on an item from section1 , you were able to display the component in section2 ?

Comment: yes @Illep. It's working to me.

Comment: @ArunkumarRamasamy This is what is happening. I am already in the route https://localhost/profile. So from here when I try to display 'welcome'. The path get's displayed as https://localhost/profile/welcome. So there's clearly no such route called https://localhost/profile/welcome set.

Comment: @Illep can you add your routing module here or create a sample project in https://stackblitz.com/?

Comment: I have added the routing code. Please have a look. @ArunkumarRamasamy

Comment: @Illep Create a sample project in github or stackblitz.com? It may easy to find out the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are not passing the correct routes to the routerLink:

```
constructor(private ngSimpleSidebarService: NgSimpleSidebarService) {
    this.defaultSidebarItems = [
        {
            name: 'Welcome',
            icon: 'fas fa-camera fa-xs',
            routerLink: ['/welcome'], // this path should be correct
            position: 'top',
        },
        {
            name: 'About',
            icon: 'fas fa-camera fa-xs',
            routerLink: ['/user/signin'], // this path should be correct
            position: 'top',
        },
        
    ];
    this.ngSimpleSidebarService.addItems(this.defaultSidebarItems);
    this.ngSimpleSidebarService.configure(this.defaultSidebarConfig);
  }
```

If you check the [github](https://github.com/secanis/ng-simple-sidebar/blob/master/projects/ng-simple-sidebar-showcase/src/app/app.component.ts) source code, you can check the how the routes are created. It's a sample project and worked fine as expected.

Comment: This is what is happening. I am already in the route `https://localhost/profile`. So from here when I try to display 'welcome'. The path get's displayed as `https://localhost/profile/welcome`. So there's clearly no such route called `https://localhost/profile/welcome` set.

Comment: You can add the routing for the root and the child if you are using it.  It should not append the url like this `https://localhost/profile/welcome` and it should navigate to `https://localhost/welcome` instead.

Comment: You haven't added any route which matches the route you are calling from the routerLink. I suggest you to create exact route and you will be a le to see the component.